# Can't use several Oauth in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, oauth-2.0

The problem that I can't use two SocialiteProviders at the same time
in file EventServiceProvider I have the following

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\SomeEvent' => [
        'App\Listeners\EventListener',
    ],
    \SocialiteProviders\Manager\SocialiteWasCalled::class => [
        // add your listeners (aka providers) here
        'SocialiteProviders\VKontakte\VKontakteExtendSocialite@handle',
    ],
    \SocialiteProviders\Manager\SocialiteWasCalled::class => [
        \JhaoDa\SocialiteProviders\Odnoklassniki\OdnoklassnikiExtendSocialite::class
    ],
];
```

So If the Odnoklassniki provider works, there is no possibility to use Vkontakte provider. It gives the following:

InvalidArgumentException in Manager.php line 90:
Driver [vkontakte] not supported.

And if I comment Odnoklassniki, Ir will not work also.

How to make it both work.

Answer (score 0):

When you place another item with the same key of an array, it overwrites previous value. Just add them to one key:

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\SomeEvent' => [
        'App\Listeners\EventListener',
    ],
    \SocialiteProviders\Manager\SocialiteWasCalled::class => [
        // add your listeners (aka providers) here
        'SocialiteProviders\VKontakte\VKontakteExtendSocialite@handle',
        \JhaoDa\SocialiteProviders\Odnoklassniki\OdnoklassnikiExtendSocialite::class
    ],
];
```